# tmux Meta-N not working

Tags: terminal, tmux

Recently, <kbd>M-2</kbd> (and the other <kbd>M-N</kbd>'s) have stopped working for me in `tmux`. <kbd>M-Up</kbd>, <kbd>M-Down</kbd>, etc still work. It only seems to affect the <kbd>M-NumberKey</kbd> key chords.

I can run:

```
select-layout even-vertical
```

from the <kbd>:</kbd> prompt and it still works...

The keybindings still seem correct:

```
bind-key        M-1 select-layout even-horizontal
bind-key        M-2 select-layout even-vertical
bind-key        M-3 select-layout main-horizontal
bind-key        M-4 select-layout main-vertical
bind-key        M-5 select-layout tiled
```

I'm guessing it might not actually be `tmux`'s fault since I haven't updated `tmux` recently, but I have no idea how to debug this...

I've tried with several terminal emulators (`gnome-terminal`, `xterm`, `xfce4-terminal`) in two different desktop environments (Gnome and XFCE4).

Any ideas on what's going on here or how I can debug this?

Other possibly useful info:

```
tmux version: 1.9a
Distro: Arch Linux
```

Comment: Have you tried completely quitting tmux (or rebooting), and still gotten the issue?

Comment: Yes. Turns out it's a bug in gnome-terminal with the GNOME 3.12 release.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a bug in gnome-terminal with the GNOME 3.12 release. Bug description and workaround [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=728543). Spoiler: disable the <kbd>Alt-<N></kbd> keyboard shortcuts in `Edit -> Preferences -> Shortcuts`.

Comment: Terminator has a similar poor default, where you have to disable it's use of `alt+arrows`